# FirstPersonMovement in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

there!
Greeting to all of you :-)

Im sorry if my question not interesting one. I start to code not long ago, so i think that my problem is somewhat primitive. 
I made my 3d city with help of Three.js and Isaac Sukin book named "Game Development with Three.js".

It was an easy part.
But when i tried to add movement options i wasnt able to success. 
Here is code, that work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      body {
       background-color: #ffffff;
       margin: 0;
       overflow: hidden;
      }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
      <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r57/three.min.js">      
        </script>
      <script src="FirstPersonControls.js"></script>
      <script> 


  var camera, scene, renderer, light;
  var clock, controls;



  function setup() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#00BFFF';
    setupThreeJS();
    setupWorld();

    requestAnimationFrame(function animate() {
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update(clock.getDelta());
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      });
   }

  function setupThreeJS() { 
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    clock = new THREE.Clock();
    controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
    controls.movementSpeed = 100;
    controls.lookSpeed = 0.1;   

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xf6e86d, 1 );
    light.position.set( 1, 3, 2 );
    scene.add( light );

    scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2 (0x9db3b5, 0.002);

    light.castShadow = true;
    light.shadowDarkness = 0.7;
    light.shadowMapWidth = 2048;
    light.shadowMapHeight = 2048;
    light.position.set(500, 1500, 1000);
    light.shadowCameraFar = 2500;

    light.shadowCameraLeft = -1000;
    light.shadowCameraRight = 1000;
    light.shadowCameraTop = 1000;
    light.shadowCameraBottom = -1000;    

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.y = 410;  
    camera.position.z = 400;
    camera.position.x = -55 * Math.PI / 180; // set camera position at 45 degrees down

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); 
   }

    function setupWorld() {

     // its floor
     var geo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2500, 2500, 20, 20); // first 2 parametres its size of the plane, other 2 - split the plane into 20 x 20 grid
     var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x228b22, overdraw: true});
     var floor = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
     floor.receiveShadow = true;
     floor.rotation.x = -90 * Math.PI / 180; // we set our plane at 90 degrees, so its lay directly under our building 
     scene.add(floor);    // i cant understand. at first author tell that you should use mesg, but later, that you should use floor. ok, we'll see. 

     // building
     var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1); // generate cube as basis for our builldings
     geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 0.5, 0)); // set geometry origins, the point around which the geometry is scaled and rotated
     var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/house.jpg'), overdraw: true}); // create material for our cube

     //cloned buildings
      var cityGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
      for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        var building = new THREE.Mesh(geometry.clone()); // create all our buildings. clone method allow us to create objects as clones
        building.position.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200 - 100) * 4;
        building.position.z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200 - 100) * 4;
        building.scale.x = Math.random() * 50 + 10;
        building.scale.y = Math.random() * building.scale.x * 8 + 8;
        building.scale.z = building.scale.x;
        THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(cityGeometry, building);
       }
        var city = new THREE.Mesh(cityGeometry, material);
        city.castShadow = true;
        city.receiveShadow = true;
        scene.add(city);

     }

     setup();  

      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Here is screen with derictory, where my firstattempt.html and FirstPersonControls.js located.

[Files directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7DHV.png)

FirstPersonControls.js was took from three.js/examples/js on github dot com.

Problem is that when opened in browser my city "lose" texture (which you can see on first screen) and no movement can be reached through keys. 
Moreover, in Developer tool i see this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0knck.png)

I'll be very grateful for any help. I think, that may be problem in the way how i use FirstPersonControls.js ? 
  Please, excuse me for my bad knowledge of javascript :-(

Answer (score 0):

maybe init camera before you pass it to controls

camera is of type undefined here so even if you pass it to the controls and then modify, controls dont get the "reference" to it

```
controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
```

put camera declaration before it like so...

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Its work now! :-) Ah, what a shame that   i forget about it in first place :-(